# Bootstrap Accordion não funciona quando carrega conteúdo com ajax

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho meu acordion, dentro do body dele, eu tenho uma div aonde é carregado o conteúdo via ajax

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Titulo
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="conteudo" data-url="MINHA URL PARTIAL">
Carregando
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Titulo 2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="conteudo" data-url="MINHA URL PARTIAL">Carregando</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

e para isso uso o seguinte código javascript:

```
    $(".conteudo").each(function (index, item) {
        var url = $(item).data("url");
        if (url && url.length > 0) {
            $(item).load(url);
        }
    });
```

Mas enquanto ele carrega essas views, que as vezes pode demorar,o accordion simplesmente trava e não aparece o "hover" do a link, ao clicar nas abas do accordion ele não faz nada

Algo errado?

Comment: Fica mais fácil pra quem quiser testar se vc fornecer um código plug'n'play, com html mínimo contendo `<script src>` e tal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em pesquisas, vi que é por causa da lib collapse.js que o bootstrap usa.
A mesma não obtem suporte para isso.

Uma forma de resolver, é carregar ao clicar no accordion.

Answer (score 0):

Oi,

Seu HTML está inválido. Antes do seu segundo `<div class="panel-heading">` está faltando um `<div class="panel panel-default">`.

[Aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/giulianobg/q3bamma1/) tem um exemplo funcionando.

Comment: Não sei aonde você viu faltando...mas enfim, está correto.